# Chrome save html of all loaded websites automatically

Tags: html, google-chrome, save

I need a chrome extension which saves all browsed sites automatically.

For example:

1. i browse to site www.xzy.com
2. browser saves it as soon as loaded
3. i click a button, site reloads
4. browser saves it as soon as loaded
5. page reloads several times automatically
6. browser saves all "reloaded" pages

I would only need the html source of the site.

I would need the html parts to reproduce the steps with curl later.

If i manually hit CTRL-S and save HTML it only saves the initial html not the "reloaded" ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got solved by using [Telerik's Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).